# shebang under linux does not split arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, gnu-coreutils

I have kotlin script (but it can be any Linux command with arguments) for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env kotlinc -script
println("hello world")
```

When I run it in Ubuntu I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘kotlinc -script’: No such file or directory
```

but when I run in command line:

```
/usr/bin/env kotlinc -script
```

It works. It is no problem with finding path because script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env kotlinc
println("hello world")
```

works

For some reason under Ubuntu `"#!/usr/bin/env kotlinc -script"` treats `"kotlinc -script"` as single argument. But only in shell script header.

I need explicitly to run my script `"#!/usr/bin/env kotlinc -script"` because I want it to run properly on other distributions end environments where `"kotlin"` is in `$PATH`.

Is there a bug in Ubuntu coreutils or sth? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: This is highly system specific. Some system treat shebang as a single argument, some split it on spaces. But you shouldn't count on that. And you shouldn't use it, if you want to write portable scripts, ie. scripts that will work on all systems.

Comment: Very long time ago I was dealing with a similar issue and I created a small utility to deal with different Unix-like systems treating it in different ways, see [shebang](https://github.com/dtmilano/shebang/blob/master/README)

Answer (score 8):

Starting with coreutils 8.30 (released July 2018) you can use the `-S` flag, which means “process and split into separate arguments”:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S command arg1 arg2 ...
```

You may want to upgrade your coreutils if it’s too old. As you tagged with ubuntu, you can check your coreutils version with:

```
apt-cache policy coreutils
```

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, you can't pass more than one argument via the shebang line. All arguments will be passed as a single string to the executable:

```
#!/bin/foo -a -b -c
```

will pass one option "-a -b -c" to `/bin/foo`, plus the contents of the file. Like if you would call:

```
/bin/foo '-a -b -c' contents-of-file.txt
```

The behaviour should be the same on most unix derivates nowadays, but it can differ, I haven't tested them all :)

It's hard to find proper documentation for this, the best I could quickly find was this: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#splitting

---

As a workaround you would normally create a shell wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec kotlin --arg1 --arg2 ... /path/to/kotlin-script
```

Comment: And to confuse things some interpreters like perl reprocess the shebang line themselves in order to split the arguments.

Comment: If `kotlin --arg1 --arg2 ...` is the last line of the bash wrapper, I'd suggest using the `exec` builtin and thus write `exec kotlin --arg1 --arg2 ...`: this is more efficient (one fork avoided) and more robust w.r.t. signals handling (see e.g. [this wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WrapperScript?highlight=(exec))).

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to install kotlin, since I did not yet have installed it and just downloaded https://github.com/bernaferrari/GradleKotlinConverter
and thought it should work.

```
sudo snap install kotlin --classic
```